# Akka.net cluster sharding: Unable to register coordinator

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster, akka.net-persistence

I am trying to setup akka.net cluster sharding by creating a [simple project](https://github.com/technologyblogger/clustersharding.git).

**Project layout:**

*Actors* - class library that defines one actor and message. Is reference by other projects

*Inbound* - Starts ShardedRegion and is the only node participating in cluster sharding. And should be the one hosting the coordinator too.

*MessageProducer* - Will host only shardedregion proxy to send messages to the ProcessorActor.

*Lighthouse* - seed node

[Uploaded images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LunE5.jpg) show that the coordinator singleton is not initialized and messages send through sharedregion proxy are not delivered.

Based on the blog post by petabridge, **petabridge.com/blog/cluster-sharding-technical-overview-akkadotnet/**,  I have excluded lighthouse, by setting akka.cluster.sharding.role, from participating in cluster sharding so that coordinator is not created on it.

Not sure what am I missing to get this to work.

Comment: Can't help myself but you might be able to expedite an answer by politely popping into https://gitter.im/akkadotnet/akka.net .

Comment: @mwardm thanks for the suggestion. Will try that now.

Answer (score 1):

This was already answered on gitter, but here's the tl;dr:

1. Shard region proxy needs to share the same role as a corresponding shard region. Otherwise proxy may not be able to find shard coordinator, and therefore not able to find initial location of a shard, it wants to send message to.
2. `IMessageExtractor.GetMessage` method is used to extract an actual message, that is going to be send to sharded actor. In example message extractor was used to extract string property from enveloping message, yet a receiver actor has `Receive` handler set for envelope, not a string.